# How to move SQL LocalDB 2012 system database on different drive?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, localdb

By default, SQL LocalDb creates all the system database under C:\Users profile.
I need all the databases including (system databases master, msdb etc) on D:\drive.
I know I can create User databases on D:\Drive but is it possible to create or move system databases to D:\Drive using SQL LocalDb?

Note: I know it is possible to move system database using SQL Express where one can move the databases using ALTER command and move master using startup commands. But the same operation cannot be used for SQL LocalDb.

So I am looking for SQL LocalDb solution.

Thanks,
Pare

Comment: Hi Pare. Just a quick question, when you say: " I know I can create User databases on D:\Drive", how would you do that? I dont need to move the sysdatabases, just user DB's and I already changed my connection string, my creation script for the database with the filename property and I just cant create the database in a specific folder, it always goes to the root of documents.

Comment: You need to sepcify the path when you create the database.     CREATE DATABASE Test ON ( NAME = Test_dat,FILENAME = 'D:\Data\Data.mdf',SIZE = 10,FILEGROWTH = 5 ) LOG ON ( NAME = Test_log, FILENAME = 'D:\Data\Test.ldf', SIZE = 5MB, FILEGROWTH = 5MB)

Comment: Thanks, I got it working meanwhile. I think it had something to do with the folder not existing. I'm now creating the folder before if it doesn't exist yet, and only after that I run the script. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a workaround to have my system databases in another drive. The solution is as follows:
1.Install SQL LocalDb

2.Move the user to a new location on D: drive. (You will have to create another user with admin rights to perform this operation) Refer to the article http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/87555-user-profile-change-default-location.html. Moving the user location before the first instance creation of SQL LocalDb is a critical step.

3.After moving the user, start the instance of SQL LocalDb (slqlocaldb s v11.0) on command line. So now all the system databases are created on different drive other than C:\

Note: If you do not want to move entire user, you can also move just AppData\Local folder to different drive. Right click on Local folder, select properties, go to "Location" tab and move to new location. Move the contents after you login with different user with admin rights. (AppData is a hidden folder)

Hope this solution helps others hence sharing my work around solution.

Comment: ugh, that totally sucks. Not that your solution is bad, just that the workaround needed is poor design. There should be a command line option to specify where the db is going to live.